# Any one else see the special weapons dalek?

Tags: doctor-who

In this recent Doctor Who episode, the magicians apprentice, was that actually a special weapons Dalek? Why haven't they appeared almost ever before, and why did one appear now?

Comment: They embarrass the other Daleks because they always say "Obliterate" instead of "Exterminate".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Doctor Who [wiki confirms](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Special_Weapons_Dalek) it was a Special Weapons Dalek. As to why - probably because it was on Skaro, the Dalek home world.

This isn't the first time we've seen one recently. One was seen during *Asylum of the Daleks*.

Comment: but why hasn't it appeared more often?

Comment: @tox123 The wikia also mentions: "It has been stated that the enormous power source required for its weapon resulted in high levels of radiation being released and altering the structure of the Dalek's brain, resulting in insanity. It was only used in extreme situations and was unofficially known among the Daleks as the Abomination. (PROSE: Remembrance of the Daleks)"

Comment: I seem to recall a special weapons Dalek shown towards the end of the "classic" Who episodes, during Sylvester McCoy's tenure as The Doctor, IIRC.

Comment: Yes, I remembered correctly! A special weapons Dalek is seen in the first serial of the 25th season, [Remembrance of the Daleks,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remembrance_of_the_Daleks) broadcast in October 1988.

Comment: At least one **is** [Russell T Davies' Dalek](http://www.digitaljournal.com/article/322726), the BBC doesn't currently own all the props.